# Why does the community bot upvote some things?

Tags: support, voting

[I have a question about the Community moderator bot.](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community) I have seen and understood what its mission is. I also noticed something that was weird, at least for me. The bot votes several questions. And while it clearly states that it votes down to oblivion bad questions or answers, I do not really understand how and why it votes some answers up.

I **do not have any problem with it voting up, but I do not understand its criteria for voting up an answer. Apart from that, isn't it essentially giving away free rep?**

Comment: Some interesting background [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/176211), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136540/176211), and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124141/176211) on Meta SO.

Comment: There is some confusing stuff about community here, you are too worried about powers when mostly there are none, its just a useful user that does things for people without account, nothing else. He is actually semi dumb and needs to be monkey trained.